# How to clear pseudoconstant cache?

Tags: api, cache

I find that if I create a new tag via the api, and then try to attach it to a contact with the entity_tag api, it will sometimes fail with the message "'##' is not a valid option for field tag_id".

This is because the entity_tag api checks for the existence of the tag_id using a pseudoconstant lookup -- which is a cached value. How can I easily clear that pseudoconstant cache after the tag has been created to ensure it can be added to the entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually clear caches with `civicrm_api3('AnyEntity', 'getfields', array('cache_clear' => 1));` (use any valid entity, it doesn't matter which).

However, if you are using the api to create tags, and this does not automatically clear the cached list of tags, I would consider it a bug. If you are able to reproduce it in the latest version please look in the [issue tracker](https://issues.civicrm.org) for an open bug report, and if there isn't one, please open one.

Comment: This worked. We're running 4.4.x. I diffed the tag-related api files between 4.4 and 4.6 and don't see any changes that would suggest the tags cache is cleared or rebuilt after creation.

Answer (score 2):

CRM_Core_PseudoConstant::flush() should do it.